# Make ESLint check usage of buildins unavailable in configured environment

Tags: eslint, ecmascript-5

Is it possible to make ESLint warn/error when it encounters usage of globals that are known to not exist in environment set in config, and assuming there are no polyfills?

E.g. usage of `Object.values` or `Object.assign` in ES5 env.

Answer (score 1):

If you're targeting the browser, try [eslint-plugin-compat](https://github.com/amilajack/eslint-plugin-compat). If you're using Node.js, [eslint-plugin-node](https://github.com/mysticatea/eslint-plugin-node)'s [no-unsupported-features rule](https://github.com/mysticatea/eslint-plugin-node/blob/master/docs/rules/no-unsupported-features.md) will handle this.

Comment: I'll try them out and accept the answer accordingly

Comment: I'm targeting browser. eslint-plugin-compat works for DOM APIs, but do you have any suggestions for JS buildins specifically?